# How to find and click a span class element using the text of a sibling span class

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

---

```
<div class="answersContainer">
  <div class="answer fadeIn" style="visibility: visible;">
    <span class="answerBox">
      <a name="checkboxtag" class="largecheckbox" onclick="selectQuizAnswer(this);"></a>
      <input type="radio" name="answers" value="8ad6a412466639700146729fa9d27534" 
      class="checkbox displaynone">
    </span>
    <span class="answerText">The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer fadeIn" style="visibility: visible;">...</div>
  <div class="answer fadeIn" style="visibility: visible;">...</div>
  <div class="answer fadeIn" style="visibility: visible;">...</div>
</div>
```

---

The above code, when run in a browser window, displays four checkbox, each beside a string of text, the first of which reads, "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn". All the `<div class="answer fadeIn">` elements are structured the same way as the first one (which I expanded); however, each differs from one another in its value in `<span class="answerBox">` and in its text in `<span class="answerText">`.

I am using the latest version of Selenium in Python.

How  do I use `driver.find_element` to find, and then `.click()`, the checkbox element (`<span class="answerBox">`) if I know the text(`The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn`) of the `<span class="answerText">` which is in the same `div class` (`<div class="answer fadeIn"`)?

In other words, If I am working inside a `div class`, and I know the text, but only the text, of one child `span class`, how do I use `find_element` for finding the sibling span class element or value?

For Instance, I have tried the following in Python(after importing all the necessary modules):
`answ = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text=()='The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']/preceding-sibling::span").click()`

I also thought of taking the positional approach where I find the page position of each text in`<span class="answerText">` ,then use `.click()` to select the checkbox to the left of the correct text. However, I couldn't figure out how to click the page at a certain position relative to the text. I would really appreciate if someone would help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I understand you want to do,

You can to find an element that contains the text "*The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*". Then you want to look for a radio button `<input type="radio">` and click it.

With this statement

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text=()='The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']/preceding-sibling::span").click()
```

You are trying to click on a `<span>` which isn't a clickable element by default. It is just a container element, unless you customize it to be clickable element via `JavaScript`.

Hence the radio button isn't getting clicked.

What you should do it, look for the `<input type="radio">` inside that `<span>` and click it.

This is what I tried in `Java` and it worked,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']/preceding-sibling::span/input")).click();
```

It's `Python` translation (referring your code) would be,

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']/preceding-sibling::span/input").click()
```

Comment: can you please help me with this?
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/50474/cant-find-a-specific-element-generated-in-devexpress