# Can't find a specific element generated in DevExpress

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, visualstudio

I am attempting to find an element using this code:

```
try
{
new WebDriverWait(wdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("messageGrid_TL")));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Grid: Loading element exists");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Grid: Loading element does not exist");
            }
```

I tried all methods like ElementExists, PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy etc.,
but Standard Output is still "Grid: Loading element does not exist".
I tried to find the element by

```
//*[@id='messageGrid_TL']
//*[@id='messageGrid_LPV']
"//span[text()='Loading...']"
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Element is displayed on the page only for a few seconds.
**Note**: I don't call the loading panel from the app code, but DevExpress does it itself, when the grid is refreshed/loaded, it generates the loading panel.
Can you advise me how to find this element, please?

Answer (score 0):

Handling devExpress grids can be quite challenging, Have a look into Awaitility, it handles devexpress loading a lot better than just explicitly waiting, if you dont want to use awaitility you can also create a method to wait for the element to display and if the element displays wait for it to disappear, I can send a code snippet if you need.

Comment: Can you send a code snippet, please?